# How to add subview above the keyboard in monotouch/Xamarin.Ios?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios

How can i add a UIView on top of the keyboard in monotouch/Xamarin.Ios?

i have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.Window.AddSubview (myView);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.Window.BringSubviewToFront (myView);
```

The UIView is added behind the keyboard.

In Objective c i was able to use the following code and it worked.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:myView];
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked for me.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[1].AddSubview(myView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to create a new UIWindow at the same level as status bar. You can put this code in your ViewDidLoad override:

```
newWindow = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
newWindow.WindowLevel = UIWindow.LevelStatusBar;
```

And then add your View (in this case a button) to the new UIWindow:

```
var uIButton = new UIButton (UIButtonType.InfoDark) {
    Frame = new RectangleF (10, 400, 30, 30)
};
newWindow.AddSubview (uIButton);
```

In the UITextField, add an event listener for the EditingDidBegin

```
MyInput.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    newWindow.Hidden = false;
};
```