# How to use Core Graphics in a UIViewController's Subview in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit, core-graphics

I have set up the following structure in my storyboard. I have a UIViewController that contains a UIView which contains buttons, text, and a smaller UIView. I would like to draw to the smaller UIView.

The current working code I have is:

```
public partial class MyDrawingController : UIViewController
{
    public MyDrawingController (IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public override void LoadView ()
    {
        base.LoadView ();
        View = new NewDrawingView ();
    }
}

public class NewDrawingView : UIView
{
    public NewDrawingView () : base() {}

    public override void Draw (CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);
        DrawMe (rect);
    }

    public void DrawMe(CGRect rect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
}
```

This results in the larger UIView's content being entirely replaced by my drawing (covering my text and buttons).

```
    NewDrawingView = new NewDrawingView();
```

While this calls the constructor, the UIView's Draw method is never called, thereby never giving be correct access to the UIGraphics context to do drawing.

**Edit:**

```
    View.AddSubview(new NewDrawingView());
```

Also calls the constructor and not the Draw method (and doesn't appear to display a new view). How can I call the draw method of subview or otherwise draw within a subview?

Comment: Why not simply add a subview to your controller's view? That covers all existing controls and you can adjust its size either setting the `Frame` or by using AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. I am baffled that there I can't find a single example on the web of displaying a subview in a main view (or drawing in a partial view). Have you seen such an example anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I needed at long last at:

[How to add subview above the keyboard in monotouch/Xamarin.Ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322332/how-to-add-subview-above-the-keyboard-in-monotouch-xamarin-ios)

```
public override void LoadView ()
{
    base.LoadView ();
    NewDrawingView drawingView = new NewDrawingView{
        Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, 100, 100)
    };
    View.AddSubview (drawingView);
}
```

This code correctly initializes my drawing view and calls the draw method when adding the subview to the view controller's main view.